# PHP exec and amixer

Tags: sudo, php, exec

I'm trying to make php lower the dB level of amixer using exec, but it seems like php isn't able to perform the task which requires sudo-access. What should be the best way to solve this?

I tried:

PHP (each line is a own attempt)

```
echo shell_exec("sudo -u MYUSERNAME sh /var/www/html/music/volume.sh");
echo exec("sudo -u MYUSERNAME sh /var/www/html/music/volume.sh");
echo exec("sudo -u MYUSERNAME /var/www/html/music/volume.sh");
```

VISUDO

```
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
www-data ALL=(MYUSERNAME) NOPASSWD: /var/www/html/music/volume.sh
```

Comment: You should use the [alsa api](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/ALSA_Library_API) instead or maybe pulseaudio + dbus api? BTW, there are no errors in the server log?

Comment: is `exec` and `shell_exec` enabled? normally they are disabled.

Comment: Both are enabled :)

Comment: @Braiam , I do get errors after checking; "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified"

Comment: That means that sudo is asking for a password and has no way to get one. Do the `sudo ...` lines work from a `www-data`-terminal?